# Bash script won't run

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to run a bash script named 'serverloadtest.sh' to test a server is performing correctly. However, when I type `serverloadtest.sh` all I get is 'command not found'. I'm definitely typing the right script name...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to using `./serverloadtest.sh`, as DisplayName said, make sure your script is executable. If it's not, use `chmod` to change the permissions. For example, `chmod 755 serverloadtest.sh` will give you read/write/exec permissions and others read/exec permissions, or `chmod u+x serverloadtest.sh` will give you (the owner) exececute permissions, in addition to the permissions you already have.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the folder, run `./serverloadtest.sh` instead.

If you are not in the folder you must `cd` into the folder where `serverloadtest.sh` is, or type out the full path.

Answer (score 1):

Just type `sh serverloadtest.sh` or `/usr/local/.../serverloadtest.sh` or change your current directory to where this script is and type `./serverloadtest.sh`

Try to read about how to run shell scripts.